# Access & SQL Server: Number of uses since date aggregate problem - new reporting problem (solved aggregate issue)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, aggregate-functions

**BACKGROUND:**
I've been trying to streamline the work involved in running a report in my program.  Lately, I've had to supply a listing of job numbers an instrument has been used on with the listing of items for cost/benefit analysis.  Mostly to see how often an instrument is used since it was last serviced/calibrated and the last time anyone did use it.  I was looking to integrate this into the query that helps generate the report - but I keep hitting a brick wall of sorts with the number of uses - since I want that aggregate to be based on the date the instrument was last calibrated (a field based in the same query).  I can get it to give me the number of uses in the system total - but it will not accept the limitation that I want it to be only counting the times used since the last time it was calibrated

**PROBLEM:**
Attempts to put an aggregate function in my report for the number of uses since the item's calibration are met either with undesired results, or the dreaded 'aggregate missing' error (don't remember the exact warning).

-- Edited to add 8/12/2011 @ 16:09 --

An additional problem with the use of the Max aggregate has been found for instruments that have never been used being excluded by this query.

**DETAILS:**

Here is the query that does work so far:

```
SELECT
  dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail.intGagePOID,
  dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail.strGageDetailID,
  dbo_Gage_Master.Description,
  dbo_Gage_Master.Manufacturer,
  dbo_Gage_Master.Model_No,
  dbo_Gage_Master.Gage_SN,
  dbo_Gage_Master.Unit_of_Meas,
  dbo_Gage_Master.User_Defined,
  dbo_Gage_Master.Calibration_Frequency,
  dbo_Gage_Master.Calibration_Frequency_UOM,
  dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail.bolGageLeavePriceBlank,
  dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail.intGageCost,
  dbo_Gage_Master.Last_Calibration_Date,
  dbo_Gage_Master.Next_Due_Date,
  dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail.bolGageEvaluate,
  dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail.bolGageExpedite,
  dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail.bolGageAccredited,
  dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail.bolGageCalibrate,
  dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail.bolGageRepair,
  dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail.bolGageReturned,
  dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail.bolGageBER,
  dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail.intTurnaroundDaysOut,
  qryRCEquipmentLastUse.MaxOfdatDateEntered
FROM (dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail
  INNER JOIN dbo_Gage_Master ON dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail.strGageDetailID = dbo_Gage_Master.Gage_ID)
  INNER JOIN qryRCEquipmentLastUse ON dbo_Gage_Master.Gage_ID = qryRCEquipmentLastUse.Gage_ID
ORDER BY dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail.strGageDetailID;
```

But I can't seem to aggregate a count of Uses (making a Count(strCustomerJobNum)) from the tblGageActivity with the following fields:

```
strGageID
strCustomerJobNum
datDateEntered
datTimeEntered
```

I tried to add a field to the formerly listed query to do a Count(strCustomerJobNum) where datDateEntered matched the Last_Calibration_Date from the calling query - but I got the 'missing aggregate' error.  If I leave this condition out - it will run - but will list every instrument ever sent out only if it's had a usage count of at least one (not what I want at all, sadly).

I also want to make sure that if I should get a zero uses count - I will get a zero back instead of my expected records minus the null results.

I hope someone out there can tell me where I am going wrong with this - I want to save the time I am currently spending running an activity report in another program whenever I want to generate this report.  Thanks in advance, and let me know if you need me to post more information.

-- Edited to add 08/15/2011 @ 14:41 --

I managed to solve the Max() aggregate problem by creating a 'pure' first-step query to get a listing of all instrument with most modern date as qryRCEquipmentUsed.

**qryRCEquipmentLastUse**:

```
SELECT dbo.tblGageActivity.strGageID, Max(dbo.tblGageActivity.datDateEntered) AS datLastDateUsed
FROM dbo.tblGageActivity
GROUP BY dbo.tblGageActivity.strGageID;
```

Then I created a 'pure' listing of all instruments that have no usage at all as a query named qryRCEquipmentNeverUsed.

**qryRCEquipmentNeverUsed**:

```
SELECT dbo_Gage_Master.Gage_ID, NULL AS datLastDateUsed
FROM dbo_Gage_Master LEFT JOIN dbo_tblGageActivity ON dbo_Gage_Master.Gage_ID = dbo_tblGageActivity.strGageID
WHERE (((dbo_tblGageActivity.strGageID) Is Null));
```

NOTE:  The NULL was inserted so that the third combining UNION query will not fail due to a mismatch in the number of fields being retrieved from the tables.

At last, I created a UNION query named qryCombinedUseEquipment to combine the two into a list:

**qryCombinedUseEquipment**:

```
SELECT *
FROM qryRCEquipmentLastUse
UNION SELECT *
FROM qryRCEquipmentNeverUsed;
```

Using this last union query to feed the Last Used date to the parent query works in datasheet view, but when the parent query is called in the report - I get a blank report; so a nudge in the right direction would still be wonderfully appreciated.

---

**APPENDIX**

Same script as above, but with shorter table aliases (in case someone finds that clearer):

```
SELECT
  gd.intGagePOID,
  gd.strGageDetailID,
  gm.Description,
  gm.Manufacturer,
  gm.Model_No,
  gm.Gage_SN,
  gm.Unit_of_Meas,
  gm.User_Defined,
  gm.Calibration_Frequency,
  gm.Calibration_Frequency_UOM,
  gd.bolGageLeavePriceBlank,
  gd.intGageCost,
  gm.Last_Calibration_Date,
  gm.Next_Due_Date,
  gd.bolGageEvaluate,
  gd.bolGageExpedite,
  gd.bolGageAccredited,
  gd.bolGageCalibrate,
  gd.bolGageRepair,
  gd.bolGageReturned,
  gd.bolGageBER,
  gd.intTurnaroundDaysOut,
  lu.MaxOfdatDateEntered
FROM (dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail gd
  INNER JOIN dbo_Gage_Master gm ON gd.strGageDetailID = gm.Gage_ID)
  INNER JOIN qryRCEquipmentLastUse lu ON gm.Gage_ID = lu.Gage_ID
ORDER BY gd.strGageDetailID;
```

Comment: Try to formulate you issue/question/problem without a lot of details and text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Summary Problem:**

Attempts to put an aggregate function in my report for the number of uses since the item's calibration are met either with undesired results, or the dreaded 'aggregate missing' error.

**Solution:**

I decided to leave the query driving the report alone - instead choosing to employ the use of DLookup and DCount as appropriate to retrieve the last used date from a query that provides the last used date of all the instruments, and the number of uses an instrument has had since it's last calibration, using the aforementioned domain aggregates respectively.

Using the query described in the problem description, I am able to retrieve the last used date for all instruments.  I used a =DLookup statement as the source for a text box on the report's subreport dealing with various items as such:

```
=IIf((DLookUp("[qryRCCombinedUseEquipment]![datLastDateUsed]","[qryRCCombinedUseEquipment]","[qryRCCombinedUseEquipment]![strGageID]=[strGageDetailID]")) Is Null Or ([bolGageReturned]=True),"",DLookUp("[qryRCCombinedUseEquipment]![datLastDateUsed]","[qryRCCombinedUseEquipment]","[qryRCCombinedUseEquipment]![strGageID]=[strGageDetailID]"))
```

This allows items that have never been used to return a NULL result, which will display as a blank text box.

The number of uses, however, would not feed off a query using =DCount (I tried, it would take over ten minutes to retrieve results, if it ever did).  However, using the underlying activity table, I used the following statement:

```
=IIf([bolGageReturned],"","Used " & DCount("[dbo_tblGageActivity]![strGageID]","[dbo_tblGageActivity]","[dbo_tblGageActivity]![strGageID] = [strGageDetailID] And [dbo_tblGageActivity]![datDateEntered]  Between [txtLastCalibrationDate] And date()") & " times since last calibration")
```

It would retrieve a number of times used since the instrument was last calibrated, but no uses that are before that or after today (some jobs are post dated, strangely).  Of course, this is SLOW (about thirty seconds for a large document with thirty or forty instruments).

Does anyone else have a better solution for this, or will I have to take the performance hit?  If no one has any better ideas, I will accept this as the answer after five days (8/21/2011) .

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
    SELECT dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail.intGagePOID, dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail.strGageDetailID, 

        OuterGageMaster.Description, OuterGageMaster.Manufacturer,   OuterGageMaster.Model_No, 

        OuterGageMaster.Gage_SN, OuterGageMaster.Unit_of_Meas, OuterGageMaster.User_Defined, 

        OuterGageMaster.Calibration_Frequency, OuterGageMaster.Calibration_Frequency_UOM, 

        dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail.bolGageLeavePriceBlank, dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail.intGageCost, 

        OuterGageMaster.Last_Calibration_Date, OuterGageMasterNext_Due_Date, 

        dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail.bolGageEvaluate, dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail.bolGageExpedite, 

        dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail.bolGageAccredited, dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail.bolGageCalibrate, 

        dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail.bolGageRepair, dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail.bolGageReturned, 

        dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail.bolGageBER, dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail.intTurnaroundDaysOut, 

        qryRCEquipmentLastUse.MaxOfdatDateEntered,

        (Select Count(strCustomerJobNum) 

             FROM tblGageActivity WHERE   

              OuterGageMaster.Last_Calibration_Date=tblGageActivity.datDateEntered) As   JobCount

FROM 

    (dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail INNER JOIN dbo_Gage_Master OuterGageMaster ON 

    dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail.strGageDetailID = OuterGageMaster.Gage_ID) INNER JOIN 

    qryRCEquipmentLastUse ON OuterGageMaster.Gage_ID = qryRCEquipmentLastUse.Gage_ID

ORDER BY

 dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail.strGageDetailID;
```

or is that what you tried?

Comment: This seems credible. Your answer, however, might have been overlooked because of its unpresentability.

Comment: Actually, I will look it over - see how it differs from my current query.  The expanded table names are helpful to me, as I have a hard time remembering what alias went with what when - but I do plan to shorten them once it comes to putting this program out for general use for maintainability sake.

Comment: Your query doesn't have a proper INNER JOIN syntax, and my attempts to translate it result in the application crashing on attempting to save or run this query.

Answer (score 1):

Piece by piece...

First -- I suspect you're trying to answer too many questions at once (as evidenced by 23 fields in your SELECT), which will make aggregation near-impossible.  Start by narrowing down the scope of the query -- What question is this query attempting to answer?  (You can always make more queries to answer other questions... :-)

1) How many uses since last calibration?
2) How many uses since last ...*use*?  (not sure what you mean by that -- maybe last sign-out, or last rental, etc.?)

Tip -- learn to use table aliases.  Large queries are difficult to read; worse because of repeated table names.

1) Ex.: dbo_tbl_POGaugeDetail.intGagePOID becomes d.intGagePOID

Here's a sample that might get you started:

```
SELECT
   d.strCustomerJobNum,
   Max(d.last_calibration_date) -- not sure what you named that field
   Count(d.strCustomerJobNum)
FROM
   dbo_tblPOGaugeDetail d
GROUP BY
   d.strCustomerJobNum
```

Comment: The problem is that all the information in the query is information used on the report generated, and is required for the report to serve its purpose - so I am not sure I can really cut it down more than it already is.  Good tip on the table aliases, BTW, I will see about implementing this in the program's design - this puppy is still very much 'Alpha' software (only I use it at present).  The 'Last Use' field is to show the date the item was last used in a customer job - it's a common question I get asked on this kind of report.