# MySQL: Ordering By Using Two Counts From Another Table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have one sql table that looks like this called "posts":

```
id | user
--------------------------------
0  | tim
1  | tim
2  | bob
```

And another called "votes" that stores either upvotes or downvotes on the posts in the "posts" table:

```
id | postID | type
--------------------------------
0  | 0      | 0
1  | 2      | 1
2  | 0      | 1
3  | 0      | 1
4  | 3      | 0
```

In this table, the 'type' is either a 0 for downvote or 1 for upvote.

How would I go about ordering posts by "tim" by the number of (upvotes - downvotes) the post has?

Comment: Essentially, Tim's first post (`id=0`) has 2 upvotes and 1 downvote, so the score is 1. While his second post (`id=1`) doesn't have any votes so it has a score of zero. SO the goal is that when these are selected (`SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user='tim' ORDER BY <post score> DESC`) we can somehow order by there score without adding a new field to the posts table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  p.user,
  SUM(v.type * 2 - 1) AS votecount
FROM posts p
  LEFT JOIN votes v ON p.id = v.postID
WHERE p.user = 'tim'
GROUP BY p.id, p.user
ORDER BY votes DESC
```

---

**UPDATE** – `p` and `v` explained.

In this query, `p` and `v` are *aliases* of, respectively, `posts` and `votes`. An alias is essentially an alternative name and it is defined only within the scope of the statement that declares it (in this case, the SELECT statement). Not only a table can have an alias, but a column too. In this query, `votecount` is an alias of the column represented by the `SUM(v.type * 2 - 1)` expression. But presently we are talking only about tables.

Before I go on with explanation about table aliases, I'll briefly explain why you may need to prefix column names with table names, like `posts.id` as opposed to just `id`. Basically, when a query references more than one table, like in this case, you may find it quite useful always to prefix column names with the respective table names. That way, when you are revisiting an old script, you can always tell which column belongs to which table without having to look up the structures of the tables referenced. Also it is *mandatory* to include the table reference when omitting it creates ambiguity as to which table the column belongs to. (In this case, referencing the `id` column without referencing the `posts` table does create ambiguous situation, because each table has got their own `id`.)

Now, a large and complex query may be difficult to read when you write out complete table names before column names. This is where (short) aliases come in handy: they make a query easier to read and understand, although I've already learnt that not all people share that opinion, and so you should judge for yourself: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034115/access-sql-server-number-of-uses-since-date-aggregate-problem-added-max-ag) contains two versions of the same query, one with long-named table references and the other with short-aliased ones, as well as an opinion (in a comment to one of the answers) why aliases are not suitable.

Anyway, using short table aliases in this particular query may not be as beneficial as in some more complex statements. It's just that I'm used to aliasing tables whenever the query references more than one.

[This MySQL documentation article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) contains the official syntax for aliasing tables in MySQL (which is actually the same as in standard SQL).

Comment: i like your manipulation to determine the vote value - its cute, nice

Comment: @Derek: Thanks. It might break if other types exist/appear, though. But I'm leaving it as is, just as an alternative to the more traditional (and reliable) CASE/IF() method.

Comment: @Andiry M: Sorry, I'm learning SQL and I would really appreciate it if you could clarify for me what those single letters do (`p` and `v`), do they just add a quick way to reference those tables? can you link me to a tutorial or tell me what they are called? Thanks.

Comment: @Tomas: Basically, yes, they are used instead of complete names for brevity. I added an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but should work:

```
select post.id, sum(if(type = 0, -1, 1)) as score
from posts join votes on post.id = votes.postID
where user = 'tim'
group by post.id
order by score
```

Do you plan to concur SO? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I cut out the subquery since in mysql its unnecessary. The original query was portable, but unnecessary for mysql.

```
select
    p.id, SUM(case 
                when v.type = 0 then -1 
                when v.type = 1 then 1 
                else 0 end) as VoteCount 
from
    posts p
    left join votes v
        on  p.id = v.postid
where
    p.[user] = 'tim'
group by
    p.id
order by
    VoteCount desc
```

Comment: i've updated it - i'm more familiar with mssql so i wrote something that would be portable. the updated query should be more tailored toward mysql

Comment: @Derek: Then you probably are not aware yet that SQL Server supports alias referencing in ORDER BY too. +1 for the good old & cross-platform CASE method, but `@`-names should probably be replaced with 'normal' ones.

Comment: @andriy wow, i just learned something new today...thanks, i had no idea